# remove left part of image srcs with javascript and regex

Tags: javascript

```
<img src="../public/images/pages/contact-685px_06.jpg" height="170" width="685"/>
```

i want to remove left part of src which starts with public.

this is the code i tried:

```
$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("../public", ""));
```

but this doesn't fit for all situations. because it is static. only removes ../public part. there is no standart for paths.
for example:
it may be ../../public instead of ../public or etc... (it may tend to left)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove everything on the left from `public` keyword (including it), use:

`str.replace(/.+public/, '')`

```js
var str1 = "./public/images/pages/contact-685px_06.jpg";
var str2 = "/awdawd/awd/public/images/pages/contact-685px_06.jpg"; 
var str3 = "even/mor3/@#4#%stuff/awdawd/awd/public/images/pages/contact-685px_06.jpg"; 

console.log(str1.replace(/.+public/, ''));
console.log(str2.replace(/.+public/, ''));
console.log(str3.replace(/.+public/, ''));
```

Comment: Why not use `.*\/` as regex (capturing and replacing everything up to the image filename :)

Comment: @Philip Your `RegExp` doesn't work actually. He wants to delete everything up to the `public` keyword, not up to the last slash `/`.

Comment: @Philip Works cool, but it's not what the OP wants exactly :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach:

```js
var imgEl = $('img');
imgEl.attr("src", imgEl.attr("src").replace(/^.+public/, ""));

console.log(imgEl.attr("src"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="../public/images/pages/contact-685px_06.jpg" height="170" width="685"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression instead of a string. The regular expression you want is "match (pairs of dots) subpaths until the public subpath is found". It can be implemented like this:

```
regex = /^(?:\.\.\/)+public\//
```

Applied to your code, in the `replace` function, will result into this:

```
$(this).attr(
  "src",
  $(this).attr("src").replace(/^(?:\.\.?\/)+public\//, "")
);
```